# how to access multiple elements selected in listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

i have set selection mode to multiExtended in vb.net
So i am able to select multiple elements but how to access those selected values/indices using SelectedItems property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedItems` gives you a [`SelectedObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedobjectcollection.aspx) which you could go through using simple indices such as:

`mySelectList.SelectedItems[0]` would give you the first selected item.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `SelectedItems` property.  Since it is an `IEnumerable` you can use for-each constructs to iterate the list.